# Cocos2d v 4.0 : PageView delegate addEventListenerPageView not found

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-x

In Cocos2d v3.17 we used below code to create PageView

```
    Size size(SW, SH);
    PageView* pageView = PageView::create();
    pageView->setDirection(PageView::Direction::HORIZONTAL);
    pageView->setContentSize(size);
    pageView->setPosition(Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f));
    pageView->removeAllItems();
    pageView->setIndicatorEnabled(true);
    pageView->setGlobalZOrder(200);
    pageView->setIndicatorIndexNodesOpacity(255);
    pageView->setIndicatorPosition(Vec2(SW*0.5, SH*0.2));

    this->addChild(pageView, 1);

    int pageCount = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i)
    {
        GBMapSelectionPage *page = GBMapSelectionPage::initWithParent(this, i);

        page->setContentSize(size);

        pageView->insertCustomItem(page, i);

    }

    pageView->addEventListenerPageView(this, pagevieweventselector(GBMapScreen::pageViewEvent));
```

Event listener

```
void GBMapScreen::pageViewEvent(Ref *pSender, PageViewEventType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case PAGEVIEW_EVENT_TURNING:
        {
            PageView* pageView = dynamic_cast<PageView*>(pSender);

            _displayValueLabel->setString(StringUtils::format("page = %ld", static_cast<long>(pageView->getCurrentPageIndex() + 1)));
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

In Cocos2dx v4.0, addEventListenerPageView missing. How to get page scroll delegate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cocos2d-x v4.0, we can use addEventListener to get PageView delegates

```
pageView->addEventListener((ui::PageView::ccPageViewCallback)CC_CALLBACK_2(GBMapScreen::pageViewEvent,this));
```

Delegate Function:

```
void GBMapScreen::pageViewEvent(Ref *pSender, ui::PageView::EventType EventType)
{
    switch (EventType)
    {
        case ui::PageView::EventType::TURNING:
            {
                PageView* pageView = dynamic_cast<PageView*>(pSender);

                int index = static_cast<int>(pageView->getCurrentPageIndex()+1);

                printf("Scrolled to Page : %d\n", index);
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```